# Useful examples of Kinect in combination with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

My colleague and I are working on a project where we need to use Kinect to control an application made in Unity. We have familiarized ourselves with Kinect and Unity, but we can't find any examples or tutorials about how to use the two together. Does anybody have any useful resources for this? As my project partner says: the more examples, the merrier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a good site with a lot of kinect projects people have worked on, with a bunch being Unity+KinectSDK
http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=kinect+unity

Answer (score 1):

Kinect with MSSDK - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/7747

Kinect with OpenNI 1.5 - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/7225

Answer (score 0):

Markerless motion capture with a kinect (or asus xtion live pro or carmine), and face animations in unity: http://www.faceshift.com/unity